# How can I locate element for ecom application , where I have a product listing page , below is HTML:

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in webdriver automation field. I am trying to click on the first product in Product listing page but I am unable to locate any product element in order to click on it. Kindly help. Already tried google and stack overflow for answers but couldn't find one to solve my issue.

My code:

```
<div class="small-6 medium-4 large-3 columns category-product cat-grid grid-view clear-both" data-name="Zivame Bandage Moderate Pushup Strapless Bra-Black" data-rating="" data-ptype="Bras" data-brand="Zivame" data-sku="B65707-Black" data-product-id="174254"
style="height: 545px;">
  <div class="image-wrapper" data-price="995" data-name="Zivame Bandage Moderate Pushup Strapless Bra-Black" title="Zivame `enter code here`Bandage Moderate Pushup Strapless Bra-Black">`enter code here`
    <div class="front pos-relative">
      <a target="_blank" href="/zivame-bandage-moderate-pushup-strapless-bra-black.html?trksrc=category&trkid=Bras">
        <img class="act-place lazy" data-small="//cdn.zivame.com/media/zcmsimages/configimages/B65707-Black/1_small.jpg" data-original="//cdn.zivame.com/media/zcmsimages/configimages/B65707-Black/1_medium.jpg" src="//cdn.zivame.com/media/zcmsimages/configimages/B65707-Black/1_medium.jpg"
        alt="Zivame Bandage Moderate Pushup Strapless Bra-Black" style="display: inline-block;">
      </a>
      <div class="product-name">
      </div>
      <div class="more-on icon-chevron-down pointer show-for-small-down"></div>
      <div class="mobile-controls show-for-small-down">
        <div class="row product-details">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns more-actions show-for-medium-up">
                <div class="check-size left text-center pointer" title="check sizes">
                  <i class="sel-product-color left pd-l10 pointer icon-palette" title="More colors in this"></i>
                  <span class="fs-10 left color-count">1</span>
                  <i class="show-similar left pd-l10 pointer icon-layers" title="More like this"></i>
                  <div class="add-to-cart-btn mr-r10">
                    <span class="shortlist-item icon-heart left pointer" title="Add to Wishlist"></span>
                    <span class="add-to-cart z-uppercase left pointer" title="Add to Cart">Add to Cart</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fav-count fs-10 ff-rr">216 people favorited this</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Which html element is it exactly that you're trying to click?

Comment: your question is vague, please elaborate, also which element are you trying to click?

Comment: I git the solution As Xpath is working fine in this case Thanks Josh and Immortal Dude. xpath:  /html/body/div[8]/div[7]/div[2]/div.